# having @ char in a string in python

Tags: python

Am generating dummy email address for testing purpose, and so wanted the following code to work

```
return "test_%@test.tm"% counter();
```

but its not working, seems some special things about @, not able to have `@` in string.

EDIT

Could somebody please tell me why output has no 'email' attribute/key present here with this example - https://gist.github.com/4505055

btw Am new to python

EDIT

my mistake, email attr was missing, sorry :(

Comment: There's something special about `%`. Did you want `"test_%s@test.tm"% counter()`?

Comment: `%@t` is an incorrect format specifier, that's why you're getting the error.

Comment: @AmolPujari: btw, you can leave out the semicolons at the ends of lines...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you forgot the [string replacement character](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations) `%s`.

```
return "test_%s@test.tm" % counter()
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because the character following the percent symbol in the string is supposed to specify what kind of value you're inserting in. For example, doing

```
"test_%i@test.tm" % 1
```

...would tell Python you want to insert an integer where '%i' is. However, '%@' isn't a recognized string insertion thing, so it won't work. [More info](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting)

A slightly more robust way to do the same thing might be this:

```
"test_{thing}@test.tm".format(thing=counter())
```

...or...

```
"test_{0}@test.tm".format(counter())
```

[More info](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

Comment: You might want to give http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting as reference for the (obsolete) ``%`` syntax, as it's definetely „normative“.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the link

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing special about the @.  It seems you are doing string replacement, but you've provided an invalid value to be replaced.

Try this instead:

```
return "test_%s@test.tm"% counter();
```

Answer (score 1):

you have a '%' character with your `@` symbol after it.  That is not a valid string conversion  type.

See:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations

perhaps you meant: `'test_%s@test.tm' % counter()`

(also, you don't need to terminate statements with semicolon;)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the formatter after the percent sign in your string.

```
return "test_%s@test.tm"% counter()
```

Also you don't have to add semicolon at the end of statements in python. In fact python wont complain about it because it is valid, but not recommended.